# Logcat capture only app log w/ Developer options off

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I'm capturing log to a file during runtime. Here is the method I use

```
private void executeCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    Log.e(TAG, "executeCommand: " + command);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
}
```

I need to capture my app log (Log.e) + some connectivity logs, so I'm filtering it like this:

`logcat -f /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.androidterminal/files/log/Terminal.log -n 1 -r 10000 -v threadtime MyAppTag:E AndroidRuntime:E AWSIotMqttManager:* System.out:* *:S`

When I have `Developer options - USB debugging` enabled, it captures the log properly. But when I run it with dev options disabled, it captures only my app log, but skipping `AWSIotMqttManager` and `System.out`.

How to make it work with `Developer options` disabled?

Comment: are you using proguard? check the proguard scripts to make sure log is not stripped from the code.

Comment: @Daniel no, I don't strip logs w/ proguard